# Thread Breaking why?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to generate a secret key in user defaults to act as a UDID for the device, but I am having trouble. The thread breaks at

```
} else if (success == 1 && secretKey == ""){
```

in the following example

```
if(success == 1 && secretKey != "")
                {
                    println("Login SUCCESS w/ key")
                    userDefaults.setValue(team, forKey: "teamid")
                    userDefaults.setValue(scout, forKey: "scout")
                    userDefaults.setValue(password, forKey: "password")
                    userDefaults.setValue(secretKey, forKey: "secretkey")
                    userDefaults.synchronize()
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondViewController", sender: self)


                } else if (success == 1 && secretKey == ""){
                    var secretKey = randomStringWithLength(15)
                    userDefaults.setValue(team, forKey: "teamid")
                    userDefaults.setValue(scout, forKey: "scout")
                    userDefaults.setValue(password, forKey: "password")
                    userDefaults.setValue(secretKey, forKey: "secretkey")
                    userDefaults.synchronize()
                    println("Login SUCCESS w/o key")
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("secondViewController", sender: self)
```

EDIT: 
(Some Background) 
The app I am creating uses subscriptions and to limit customers from logging in and out and sharing logins, the user will get an identifier that is kept on the server and is given to the device so upon login, it acts like a key. I like what drewag suggested, thank you. However, back to the earlier statement. I want to check when the user submits the login if he or she has an identifier saved and if the user does, it skips the creation of a new one and just sends the one they have along with their login.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Comment: You have show the error/crash log you are getting

Comment: FYI, you don't have to write your own algorithm for generating UDID: http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/

Comment: @AlexK Thank you! I can post the full file, but my first view controller is a login form. The app I am creating uses subscriptions and to limit customers from logging in and out and sharing logins, the user will get an identifier that is kept on the server and is given to the device so upon login, it acts like a key. I like what drewag suggested, thank you. However, back to the earlier statement. I want to check when the user submits the login if he or she has an identifier saved and if the user does, it skips the creation of a new one and just sends the one they have along with their login.

Comment: @drewag Thank you for that! I was looking for something like that.

Comment: @AnilVarghese I can post one if my above comment doesn't describe exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please explain what "the thread breaks" means. Are you getting an error message or crash, or did you just [set a breakpoint](http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode) there by accident? We cannot see your screen or read your mind.

Comment: @KurtRevis as far as I can tell I am receiving no errors. It is just breaking. The debug window is no help. I would be glad to post anything. I just can't find anything that would help.

Comment: Posted a follow up sense I fixed the breaking issue. This one is more tailored to the checking of their ID. Thanks for your help everyone!